# Using VB.net OR C# (SSIS) to write image to disk

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I'm currently creating an SSIS job that will pull picture data from a SQL database and write each picture to a file. We have an ID system that stores all images taken of staff directly to database fields, but we're going to be moving to a new system that stores all of the images as files in paths by User ID.

I have already created my main data flow that gets all of the users and the proper path, but I'm having trouble writing the script component that will create the images. I have the image data as a string, but how do I get it to go out to a file at the proper path?

This is what I currently have:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Dim filesys, folder
    filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not filesys.FolderExists("E:\\test\\" + Row.Folder) Then
        folder = filesys.CreateFolder("E:\\test\\" + Row.Folder)
    End If
End Sub
```

The final path I'm looking for is: "E:\test\" + Row.Folder + "\" + Row.CardholderID + ".jpg". This will change to include another folder needed by the program we are using.

I'm not really attached, so either vb.net or c# (ssis 2008) are fine by me, as I don't know either enough to have a preference.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a special requirement for using the scripting objects instead of the built in .net functions for file manipulation?

Comment: Also, when you say you have the image data in a string I'm not sure what you actually mean.  Is this the actual binary jpeg data stored to a string somehow?  What kind of format is it in?  It would definitely be easier to work with if you had access to the raw binary data in a stream or an array of bytes instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you are rolling your own solution versus using the built-in functionality of the [Export Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139818.aspx)

Examples

- http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/06/the-export-column-transformation/
- [http://f5debug.net/2011/04/25/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-–-part-44-–-export-column-transformations-in-ssis/](http://f5debug.net/2011/04/25/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-%E2%80%93-part-44-%E2%80%93-export-column-transformations-in-ssis/)
- http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/08/exporting-images-with-ssis.html

Comment: I was trying to roll my own because, honestly, I didn't know these other functions existed. I've been working with SSIS for a while, but mostly very simple stuff to shuffle data between different systems/database types. 

Thanks for these links, they'll get me where I need to be!

Answer (score 2):

First, let me say that I think billinkc has a better solution, but I'd like to answer the .net part of your question anyway.

Here is a lose example of how to do what you want.  I will update it with more specifics once you answer the questions I asked in the comments.

```
Dim dir As String = "e:\test\" & Row.Folder 

If Not IO.Directory.Exists(dir) Then
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir)
End If
Dim fs As New IO.FileStream(IO.Path.Combine(dir, Row.CardHolderID & ".jpg"), IO.FileAccess.Write)
Dim writer As New IO.BinaryWriter(fs)
writer.Write(<Your data>)

fs.Close()
fs.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks, this will also be useful for future things that I have in store